# Define test requirements for Bluemix Python application

Tags: python, ibm-cloud

We have a Python 3 application that is deployed and running fine in Bluemix.

In order to have Python 3 on the platform (and not Python 2) we pushed a file to Bluemix titled `runtime.txt` with one line of content:

```
python-3.5.1
```

Everything works fine, but when it comes to running tests, we have Python 2 again.
Tests are run in Bluemix devops pipeline, using a step dedicated to tests. (https://hub.jazz.net/)

How can I set up Bluemix to have a Python 3 test environment?
More generally, how to setup test environment in Bluemix?

Comment: How is your testing set up?

Comment: The tests are gathered in a python module "mytest" that is run from the bluemix pipeline. In the end, a bash script is run with "python mytest.py".

Comment: Have you tried running the Bash script with `python3` or `python-3.5.0` rather than `python`?

Comment: Yes I did, and it works with python3 (not python-3.5 altough I found it in heroku directory). But then I get another error that Django is not present. In general, I'd like to setup my test environment the same way I did for my production environment.

Comment: Can you put it in a `Procfile`? e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089374/what-should-the-python-start-command-look-like-in-bluemix

Comment: I have a `ProcFile` but it's used for execution environment, not for test environment. Do you mean I could setup another `ProcFile` dedicated to tests ?

Comment: So let me make sure I'm understanding your question correctly. You've created a Bluemix DevOps Pipeline for your project. You've added a testing stage. In your testing stage, you've written the Test command `python mytest.py` and it won't work because the DevOps stage is using Python 2. Then if you use the command `python3 mytest.py`, it is not detecting your frameworks. Is this correct?

Comment: You got it right. And of course in addition to this, my application (not the tests) runs properly running "python manage.py runserver" which implies the use of python 3 and django framework.

Comment: Hmm...let me see if I can find a contact of someone who is working on this to get their input. I understand where you're coming from, and it would be intuitive that the test would use the same Python version/environment specified by your configuration.

Comment: Thanks. The only solution I see at the moment is somewhat cumbersome: you could create another project with same configuration (Procfile, run.sh ...) but then run tests instead of application.

Comment: That came to mind as well. I would say at the time, you can set up two projects/apps a staging and production one. I'll let you know when they get back to me with the official answer.